# problema para recibir datos AJAX PHP SQL

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, mysqli

Soy aprendiz. Estoy intentando obtener datos de mi base de datos a traves de mysqli y lo ubico en el archivo validation3.php

```
<?php
      include_once "conexion2.php";     
       
$cl2 = $_POST["cl2"];
  $co2 = $_POST["co2"];
  $mx2 = $_POST["mx2"];
  $pe2 = $_POST["pe2"];
  

  if(!empty($cl2) && !empty($co2) && !empty($mx2) && !empty($pe2)) {

        comprobar($cl2,$co2,$mx2,$pe2);
  }
   
  function comprobar($cl2,$co2,$mx2,$pe2) {

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasas WHERE id = '00001'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

      $cl2 = $row["cl"];
      $co2 = $row["co"];
      $mx2 = $row["mx"];
      $pe2 = $row["pe"];

      if (!$result) {
        echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
    
?>
```

mi AJAX intento traer como prueba solo a $cl2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function foo(callback) {  
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   url: "admin/procesos/validation3.php",
   data: 'cl2='+$("#chile").val(),
   error: function(){
                        alert("Error de conexion, refresque por favor.");
                        },
   success: function (data) {
    callback(data);
                        n();
                        }
 })
 });
});
```

y en mi html quiero mostrar el dato pero no me muestra nada

```
<div id="chile"></div>
```

he intentado de muchas maneras pero no logro dar con el error.

Realicé un consol.log para verificar errores de esta forma

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function foo(callback) {  
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   url: "admin/procesos/validation3.php",
   data: 'cl2='+$("#resultado").val(),
   error: function(){
                        alert("Error de conexion, refresque por favor.");
                        },
   success: function (data) {
    console.log(data)
                        }
 })
 });
});
```

y el único error que se me muestra es este: : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

Comment: Que error te da consola?

Comment: Solo este: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' @JosueVargas

Comment: Alli te debe dar una linea donde esta el error, en el success veo un   callback(data); y un  n(); quitalo y coloca console.log(data); a ver si te trae todo normal

Comment: Muestra el mismo error. He actualizado la publicacion con el codigo para el console.log

Comment: Creo vi tu error prueba con este codigo https://jsfiddle.net/1bnscz75/

Comment: Chevere, lo añadí y ahora me muestra este error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130911/discussion-between-josue-vargas-and-lilibeth-q).

Comment: Si en la petición Ajax tú pones esto: `dataType: "json"`, debes asegurar que desde el servidor la respuesta sea SIEMPRE un JSON. Los problemas de *`Unexpected token`* generalmente ocurren porque se está recibiendo un JSON no válido. Si por ejemplo tu código entra en esta parte:  `echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta...";` ya tendrías un problema de *`Unexpected token`*, porque ese código no está respondiendo con un JSON. La solución es controlar el flujo de tu código, creando un array TAMBIÉN en los casos de error y devolver ese array con `json_encode`

Comment: Igualmente, en el caso de que haya datos en la consulta SQL, deberías crear un array con esos datos y devolverlos al cliente con `json_encode`. Eso tampoco ocurre en tu código actual. Debes saber que Ajax es una comunicación cliente/servidor en la cual por lo general envías unos datos desde el cliente al servidor para que éste los procese y devuelva una respuesta al cliente. Aquí no se ve que estés devolviendo ninguna respuesta al cliente, únicamente un mensaje de error, y además en un formato no compatible con el `dataType` que indicaste en tu petición Ajax, como señalé más arriba.

Answer (score 0):

Es importante tener el código bien estructurado para detectar posibles fallos al escribir el código, abrir y cerrar etiquetas, etc. He ordenado tu código y eliminado un ) que estaba de más prueba con esto a ver:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function foo(callback) {  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "admin/procesos/validation3.php",
            data: 'cl2='+$("#resultado").val(),
            error: function(){
                alert("Error de conexion, refresque por favor.");
            },
            success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            }
        });
    };
});
```

El error que te mostraba: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' quiere decir que al ejecutar tu código se encontró con un token inesperado.